# How to avoid focus on chrome while changing tab?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

is there any way to change tab in chrome with C# selenium and do not make chrome be focusing? I switch tab like:

```
 driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.ElementAt(i));
```

I want chrome to work in background, while I'm for example typing.
In my solution while chrome is changing tabs it gets to foreground. Headless mode is impossible, because the entire site does not seem to load.

Comment: Is it possible to launch it in a new window instead of a tab, so that if you are working the other window won't interfere with your work?

Comment: @Zorgarath It still does because the browser instance being automated gets moved to the foreground on window/tab switch. BTW, windows and tabs are the same thing as far as Selenium is concerned.